# Forward HTTP port on mikrotik 1 to an address on another mikrotik

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, nat, mikrotik-routeros

Trying to apply the Hairpin-nat concept on mikrotik1, my config is something like:

```
/ip firewall nat
add chain=dstnat dst-address=1.1.1.1 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \
  action=dst-nat to-address=192.168.2.2
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN action=masquerade
add chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.1.0/24 \
  dst-address=192.168.2.2 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \
  out-interface=LAN action=masquerade
```

But it doesn't work for me because (i think) 192.168.2.2 is defined on another mikrotik (lets call it mikrotik2), not on this one (mikrotik1) wich the configuration is being applied. Mikrotik1 only routes the 192.168.1.0/24 network, and mikrotik2 only routes the 192.168.2.0/24. 
But, the two mikrotik devices are bridged and the addresses are reachable.

Someone can help-me? I don't have any single clue of what to do in this case. How do I forward my internet traffic to port 80 on mikrotik1, to the mikrotik2 lan address?

PS: Both mikrotiks are gateways, each from a provider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that port 80 is not already in use by mikrotik1 (ip/services/disable http)

Also, you talk about bridging the two mikrotiks... I think this is a mistake, remove the bridge and add a route to 192.168.2.0/24 on mikrotik1, and a route to 192.168.1.0/24 on mikrotik2 if they don't exist already.
Mikrotik2 has to have also mikrotik1 as default gateway.

Then, you will only need

```
/ip firewall nat
add chain=dstnat dst-address=1.1.1.1 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \
  action=dst-nat to-address=192.168.2.2
```

Assuming that 1.1.1.1 is your WAN address.

[edit]

If Mikrotik1 is not Mikrotik2's gateway, you will have to add scr-nat

```
/ip firewall nat
add chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.2.2 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \
  action=src-nat to-address=[IP_LAN_MT1]
```

Where IP_LAN_MT1 is the internal IP of Mirotik1

Comment: Right, but I cant put Mikrotik2 to have mikrotik1 as default gateway.
There are two distinct WANs, 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 ,  and I route them by mk1 and mk2 respectively. What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: edited my reply adding src-nat rule

Comment: No change buddy, here:  
`/ip firewall nat  
add chain=dstnat dst-address=1.1.1.1 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \  
  action=dst-nat to-address=192.168.2.2  
add chain=srcnat out-interface=WAN action=masquerade
add chain=srcnat src-address=192.168.1.0/24 \  
  dst-address=192.168.2.2 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \  
  out-interface=LAN action=masquerade  
add chain=srcnat dst-address=192.168.2.2 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 \  
  action=src-nat to-address=192.168.2.253`  
  
no effect :/  
PS: linebreak markups dont work, sorry

Comment: Is 192.168.2.253 the Mikrotik1 LAN address?

Comment: Correct, the LAN address that connects the two mk's on mk1 is 192.168.2.253 and on mk2 is 192.168.1.253, reserved and static adresses.

Comment: They should be on the same network... 192.168.1.0/24 OR 192.168.2.0/24, or you forgot to tell us how they are interconnected.. Please post a diagram, or detailed description of your topology so we have a clear view.

Comment: There is: [My diagram](http://i.imgur.com/ircGBq0.jpg) ... nothing special xD

Comment: From your diagram, MK1 and MK2 are just linked with a switch, so if you want them to communicate you will have to put them on the same network, which is not the case (192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24). There is something wrong in your setup.

Comment: It's correct. I have two wans, and for each wan I use a routerboard, but my public ip is only present on the wan1 (in mk1) and the lan-pc I need to forward the httpport is on wan2 in mk2. What do you suggest me to do? Because there's nothing wrong in bridging my two lan-networks/mks since i don't need the isolation of the lan1 from lan2.
Theoretically it's simple, I only need to forward any incoming transmission in 1.1.1.1:80 to 192.168.2.2, but there's the nat in the way to crack out the "simpleness" :S

Comment: You need level 3 connectivity, bridge is not enough. Assign an address on MK1/LAN in 192.168.2.0/24 range, and replace {IP_LAN_MT1} by that address in my script above.

Comment: There are lvl 3 connections on each mikrotik, 192.168.2.2 in MK1 (an MK2 LAN address) and 192.168.1.2 on MK2 (an MK1 LAN address).